# How to write template function for general std::vector push_back?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two or different types of `std::vector`.

```
struct data{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

std::vector<int>  val1;
std::vector<data> val2;
```

Now I want to write a template function that would work for both `val1` and `val2`.

```
template<typename t>
void my_function(t s){
    s.push_back(...); // based on s i.e it could be std::vector<int> or std::vector<data> 
}

my_function<std::vector<int>>(val1);
my_function<std::vector<data>>(val2);
```

The problem I am facing is how can I say in the code that if the type is `std::vector<int>` do push back of `s.push_back({1})` vs if `std::vector<data>` do `s.push_back({1,2,3});`

Comment: How are `{1}` and `{1,2,3}` determined? How you determine what you are filling the vectors *with* is very important.

Comment: Not quite sure but was hoping std::vector<int> and std::vector<data> would help compiler determine

Comment: @vanta Why `{1,2,3}` and not `{7,8,9}`?

Answer (score 3):

Forget templates. Simple overloading should solve your problem:

```
void my_function(const data& d) {
  val2.push_back(d);
}

void my_function(int n) {
  val1.push_back(n);
}
```

Comment: I know ur way is quite straight forward. But curious mind still begs the question is it impossible what I was trying to achieve? Is it doable?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you want to specialize your template function,
you can do for example:

```
struct data{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

std::vector<int>  val1;
std::vector<data> val2;

template<typename t> void my_function(t s);

template<>
void my_function(std::vector<int> s){
    s.push_back({1}); 
}

template<>
void my_function(std::vector<data> s){
    s.push_back({1,2,3}); 
}

int main()
{
    my_function(val1);
    my_function(val2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you looking for...

You can templatize `my_function()` espliciting `std::vector` and extracting the type contained in this way

```
template <typename T>
void my_function(std::vector<T> & s)
 { s.push_back(getTval<T>()); }
```

(off topic: observe that I've added a `&` for parameter `s`; otherwise you pass the vector `s` as a copy and the `push_back()` add a value only in the copy that is destroyed exiting from the function)

But this solution doesn't avoid the need of a function specialization; it simply move this need in implementation of `getVal()`.

```
template <typename T>
T getTval ();

template <>
int getTval<int> ()
 { return 1; }

template <>
data getTval<data> ()
 { return {1, 2, 3}; }
```

This can be usefull if `my_function()` is a great and complex solution where the `push_back()` is the only point where the data contained in the vector change the code. Otherwise, I suppose that can be better overload or specialize the same `my_function()`.